# Switch user profile in Super Mario Maker 3DS

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, super-mario-maker

We bought Super Mario Maker for my sons birthday. He played the game first, and it is linked to his profile/mii. For the life of me, I can't find a way to switch to my own profile/mii. I searched the internet and could not find anything.

So how do I switch profiles? Or does Mario Maker 3ds not support multiple accounts...

Comment: If the Nintendo Network ID tied to the 3ds is not yours, then probably that's why is linked to your son's profile.

Comment: OK. But is there a way to switch profiles in Mario Maker so we can switch back and forth.

Comment: @pinckerman or is the game tied permanently to the nnid mii...

Comment: I don't have the 3ds version, I can't try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you actually can't, you'd need a new cartridge because each cartridge is what holds the save files or "Internal Memory"

Comment: Do you have any proof for that? I suspect the data is stored on the SD card .

Comment: @PaulHiemstra No, Inobde is right. The save data for each game is stored on the cartridge, this allows you to play your save game on other DS's. So as Super Mario Maker doesn't support multiple save games, you'll need a new cartridge to have your own account.

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox that sucks, thanks for the feedback!